# How I can create this pattern overlay effect on a photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, overlay

I would like to know how to edit the photo to get this effect?
If someone knows an action script that does this and you have to pay for it, I don't have a problem, I pay for it.

That's the edited image:
[image]

This is the original picture:
[image]

Just a pattern overlay isn't. I think.
Just clapping diagonal lines over it is not enough, I think.
The lines look irregular.
Looks like a colored engraving effect combined with a color image?
The lines mix too much with the original image. I find.
Example:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need an action. In any case you could simply record your own action if you know the steps

Here are some steps to reproduce the effect.

1. Increase the image size by resampling it, in this example I changed from 72 to 300ppi - or use a higher resolution image. The one you posted is a little too low res to get really fine line patterns
2. Duplicate the original image layer
3. Rotate it 45 degrees
4. Convert to a smart object
5. Edit the smart object by double clicking it
6. Do *Filter > Sketch > Halftone pattern*, and set the Pattern Type to "Line". Adjust the size etc, until you are happy

[image]

7. Close the smart object and save the changes when prompted
8. Back in the main document, rotate the smart object back to its proper orientation
9. Set the layer blending mode to Soft Light
10. Add a black and white adjustment layer
11. Lower the opacity of that adjustment layer to 90%
12. Add a brightness contrast adjustment layer
13. Check the "Use legacy" option, and reduce the brightness and contrast

Example showing the various layers etc:

[image]

14. If the halftone pattern lines are too smooth, perhaps you could filter the Smart Layer using the Dry Brush filter.

Something like this perhaps

[image]

15. The lines are still a bit thick, so I applied a Maximum filter too

[image]

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help, effort and ambitions.
This help me and I can experiment with your info.
Have a good time.
Kind Regards,
Elena